# ALB is not accessible via Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-application-load-balancer

Let's consider my domain as "domain.com," and I've set up two Route 53 records:

1. "cloudfront.domain.com": This is a Route 53 record configured for CloudFront.
2. "alb.domain.com": This is another Route 53 record configured for an Application Load Balancer (ALB).

I've added "alb.domain.com" as an origin in CloudFront, and I've configured CloudFront to route any requests with the prefix "/api" to "alb.domain.com."

Here's the issue I'm facing:

- When I access "https://alb.domain.com/api," it successfully reaches the ALB without any problems, and I receive a response from my ECS service.
  However, when I access "https://cloudfront.domain.com/api," I encounter an HTTP 502 error, and the request doesn't reach the ALB.
- I experimented by using another ALB that listens on port 80 (HTTP) without a Route 53 URL, and it worked as expected. However, the combination of an ALB with a Route 53 URL (HTTPS) doesn't seem to be working.

Does anyone see any potential issues with this setup, or have suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem? Your insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've configured the listener rule with the host header 'alb.domain.com,' which is why you can access the endpoint. However, you forgot to include the host header for 'cloudfront.domain.com.'

Comment: I've also associated two distinct SSL certificates with the ALB  and CloudFront. These certificates belong to the same domain but are located in different regions. It was because Cloudfront certificate has to be from us-east-1, but my other resources are in other region. Could this potentially pose an issue?

Comment: Yes, this issue about SSL connection. Can you follow the link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html which help to solve the 502 issues

Answer (score 0):

You've configured the listener rule with the host header 'alb.domain.com,' allowing access to the endpoint. However, you overlooked including the 'cloudfront.domain.com' host header for the same target group.

[ELB Rules Doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-host-based-routing-support-for-aws-application-load-balancers/)

[Http 502 Bad gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html)

Comment: Thank you. There wasn't any rule for host header earlier. Now I applied the below rule, but I'm still getting 502 error. Is this configuration correct?

HTTP Host Header is alb.domain.com OR cloudfront.domain.com

Comment: Can you use the below link to solve the 502 gateway issues
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/http-502-bad-gateway.html